# Javascript Phone Number Validation- error message erace

Tags: javascript, dom

Goal:

Phone number must be entered in this format, 208-111-1111; otherwise it shows the error message. 
What is the best way to show the error message when the user entered in the correct format but if the user re-entered in the correct format, the error message will disappear.

```
JS
phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone");


var result = phoneNumber.toString().match(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/);

function validatePhone(){
if (result == null)
{
error2.innerHTML = "The number is not in a correct format";
} else 
{
error2.innerHTML = " ";
};
}

HTML
<p>Phone:</p> 
      <input type = "text" id="phone" name="phone" onChange="validatePhone()">
      <br>
      <span id="error2" ></span>
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: You are totally right. I should definitely do that. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function validatePhone() {
  phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone");
  var result = phoneNumber.value.match(/^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?$/);
  if (result == null) {
    error2.innerHTML = "The number is not in a correct format";
  } else {
    error2.innerHTML = " ";
  };
}
```

```html
<p>Phone:</p>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" oninput="validatePhone()">
<br>
<span id="error2"></span>
```

Comment: Wow it works as I wanted. I will try to understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: @charlieyu if my answer helped you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Okay. I think I did now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `phoneNumber.toString()` call.

Calling `toString()` on a DOM input element does not return the value of the user input. `toString()` is intended to provide a string representation of the object it is called on, not retrieve a value held by the object.

`phoneNumber.value` will return the value you are looking for.